# Problems with shuffling characters in a string

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, shuffle

I want to shuffle a certain String for an assignment. When I try to do it like this it throws a `NullPointerException`.

```
for (char d : masterCode.toCharArray()) {
    possibleLetters.add(d);
}
Collections.shuffle(possibleLetters);
for (char c : possibleLetters) { // arraylist of characters
    sb.append(c); //stringbuilder
    masterCode = sb.toString();
}
```

So I tried it another way:

```
masterCode = masterCode.substring(0, 4);
for (char d : masterCode.toCharArray()) {
    possibleLetters.add(d);
}
Collections.shuffle(possibleLetters);
for (char c : possibleLetters) { // arraylist of characters
    //sb.append(c); //stringbuilder
    masterCode = masterCode.concat(Character.toString(c)); // string
}
```

but this doesn't give the expected result either. `masterCode` is *ECAB* first, then it for the next output it is *CCBA*.

`masterCode` is a string from randomly generated characters, not allowing duplicates, in another method.

The question: what is a good way to fix this?

Comment: Do you initialize `sb`?

Comment: try to work with `Char` and not `char`

Comment: In the second example: you're appending these chars to the existing String `masterCode`. The old content of this String is still there.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this follows on from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27987066/1945631) to one of Arrrow's previous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In example one, are you sure `sb` is initialised using `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();`? Check the stack trace for the error, it probably shows that `sb` is null.

In example two the line `masterCode = masterCode.concat(Character.toString(c));` appends your characters. You need to set `masterCode = ""` first. As per [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)), this method:

> Concatenates the specified string to the end of this string.

Comment: yes, I forgot that I removed the declaration in the superclass because I didn't need it there anymore, then reused it here. it still gives different characters in the output though. output for the first time is: "CDBF" and after that it becomes "DCEF"

Comment: @Arrrow If you write a new question, then please add some more code. I guess you're error is somewhere else, because your current code won't "create" complete new characters like the `E` in your example.

Comment: @Arrrow You're going to need a new question for that problem, with the code you are now using as a result of this answer. Your questions are well written, so don't be afraid to ask more 

(sorry Tom, your comment was originally after mine so made more sense, but I spelt Arrrow's name with two few 'r's so deleted and recommented)